# Greenfoot: Converting a double into an intenger; int cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java, casting, double, greenfoot

I want to turn any double value into an intenger.
I know that the part behind the comma will be lost.

```
import java.lang.*;

public int doubleToIntenger(double dbl){
    int intenger;
    intenger = intenger.intValue(dbl);
    return intenger;
}
```

But I'm getting this error as a tooltip in my editor:

```
int cannot be dereferenced
```

Comment: What do you think `intenger` holds? What would be the value or reference that it is holding currently? what do you think `int intenger;` does?

Comment: Its just a simple declaration. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: You may not call methods on primitive types. Importing java.lang.* is useless, too.

Comment: Ok, thanks ;D I'm not very experienced in java. I have to find a way to convert an double into an intenger. This was my first idea.

Comment: Your first idea should be to google for "convert double to integer in Java". Note that it's spelt "integer", not "intenger". Trying random code is not an effective solution.

Comment: The majority of Germans will spell it "integer"...

Comment: One more thing: avoid imports with asterisk - they are a maintenance risk, and there's no need at all to import anything from the `java.lang` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast double to int, if you only care about before fraction.
But be carefull

```
double x = 1.999999;
int val = (int)x;// val will be 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I have already tried it with casting, but I got an error. Seems to be something else.

Comment: @phyyyl If the double value comes from a arithmetic operation, you have to think before casting it. Because 1.0 *2 does not have to be resulted as 2.0. It can be 1.99999998. Floating point arithmetic does not produce exact results.

Comment: So I should round the value first and than cast it?

Comment: @phyyyl Yes you can do that, but rounding 1,51 will result as 2. You can use epsilon arithmetic if you dont want that behavior.

Comment: I would round to the first decimal place after the comma.                         1,51 -> 1,5 -> 1 ; 1,999 -> 2,0 -> 2